# Can 2 objects have the same key name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I wonder if 2 objects can have the same key name?
They wouldn't be the same class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

An entity is uniquely identified by its path, which is the kind & name or ID of the entity and all of its ancestors. If two entities have the same name, but different kinds and/or ancestries, they will have distinct paths.